# Using itertools permutations and product to return all possible character orderings

Tags: python, product, permutation, python-itertools

I am having a bit of difficulty merging itertools permutations and product to get the output (list) I desire. I am trying to generate all orderings of characters with consideration for wildcard chars (?, *).

For instance, if input is A?, I am trying to get the following output:
AA
AB
BA
AC
CA
AD
DA ... etc

The code below does a great job of generating all permutations, with the wildcards left in.

```
chars = "HELLO?"
for i in range(len(chars)+1):
    perms = map(''.join, permutations(chars,i))
    for perm in perms:
        print(perm)
```

And this code allows me to substitute wildcard chars with all 26 possible alphabetic characters.

```
chars = "HELLO?"
wilds = [('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z') if char == "?" else (char) for char in chars]
 
 for p in itertools.product(*wilds):
     print(p)
```

What is the best way to combine these two segments (most efficient) to get the output I am looking for? Is there a better, more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just nest your two `for` loops! Append the values to a list if you want, but it will be big; if memory is a concern and you only need the values once I'd use a generator:

```
import itertools


def perm_with_wild_generator(chars):
    wilds = [('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
              'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z') if char == "?" else (char) for char in chars]

    for p in itertools.product(*wilds):
        for i in range(len(p) + 1):
            perms = map(''.join, itertools.permutations(p, i))
            for perm in perms:
                yield perm


for c in perm_with_wild_generator("HELLO?"):
    print(c)
```

The duplicates you mention in comments are because the outputs of `itertools.product` which are separately permuted share 5/6 of their letters. This code replaces `product` (recursively to handle multiple wilds) and eliminates duplicates:

```
import itertools

def replace_wild(chars, wilds):
    if '?' not in chars:
        yield chars
    else:
        for wild in wilds:
            for w in replace_wild(chars.replace("?", wild, 1), wilds):
                yield w


def perm_with_wild_generator(chars):
    wilds = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
             'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'} - set(chars)

    for i in range(len(chars) + 1):
        perms = map(''.join, itertools.permutations(chars, i))
        for perm in perms:
            for w in replace_wild(perm, wilds | set(perm.replace('?', ""))):
                yield w


for c in perm_with_wild_generator("HELLO?"):
    print(c)
```

In python 3, using `yield from` would simplify a bit.

Comment: One of the problems I am having is occurring in your code above. If you run this, it prints out all permutations in a loop, and has 26 copies of each permutation. If I run this for "HELLO?" it runs for a really long time. Even running this with "He?" takes a while. This also makes me think the permutation list can possibly be constructed in a more efficient manner. Maybe using a set or dictionary to weed out redundant perms?

Comment: That's odd. This exact code runs in 0.0005 seconds for me and only prints 2 of each permutation (because of the 2 'L's in hello). Are you sure you're using `itertools.permutation`?

Comment: Yup, I can copy and paste the block above and it runs for about 5 minutes, iterating through the perm_with_wild_generator print statement 26 times.

Comment: try it here? https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: I just played a bit there, and it does look like it stops, but I think what is happening is that the shell there is limited to a certain number of lines of output. Try "HELLOA?" and you will see the output never even gets past 5 letters. If you try "HA?" you will see the looping behavior I am talking about. 

On my end I have run this from command line in Python 3, in a Jupyter Notebook, and in Thonny and get the same iterative results.

Comment: You're right about the 'looping' -- it's because you're permuting each of the 26 products, which have 5/6 of their letters the same as one another, so any permutation not containing the wild is duplicated. I'm still not sure why it's taking so long for you, it never takes more than a fraction of a millisecond on my machine.

Comment: Any idea on how to efficiently avoid the looping? I was thinking about trying to store each in a set if it did not already exists in a set.

Comment: The new code in the answer should avoid almost all of them

Comment: I just updated it to fix a missing case -- now there are some duplicates but a lot fewer than 26